# Error: missing revert data in call exception; Transaction reverted without a reason string

Tags: ethereum, opensea

I am trying to buy an NFT from OpenSea. I can createOrder() which opens up my Metamask wallet and prompts me to SIGN, but after I sign, the code then moves on to the fulfillOrder() method which is throwing the `missing revert data in call exception` error.

```
const { executeAllActions } = await seaport.createOrder(
    {
      offer: [
        {
          amount: parseEther(ethAmount).toString(),
          // WETH on goerli
          token: "0xB4FBF271143F4FBf7B91A5ded31805e42b2208d6",
        },
      ],
      consideration: [
        {
          itemType: ItemType.ERC721,
          token: contractAddress,
          identifier: tokenId,
          recipient: walletAddress,
        },
      ],
    },
    walletAddress
    );
const order = await executeAllActions();

const { executeAllActions: executeAllFulfillActions } =
await seaport.fulfillOrder({
  order,
  accountAddress: walletAddress,
});
```

```
Error: missing revert data in call exception; Transaction reverted without a reason string [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ] (data="0x", transaction={"to":"0xe2De2249Cf1C9d76EAF24257B85BBE83Bd218a0B","data":"0x6352211e0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000019","accessList":null}, error={"rawMessage":"Error forwarded from node: execution reverted","code":-32603,"message":"Magic RPC Error: [-32603] Error forwarded from node: execution reverted"}, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=providers/5.7.2)
```

Not sure how to debug this since the error says `Transaction reverted without a reason string`. Any thoughts are appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Solved by @emo_eth on Twitter.

Seems like the error data "0x6352211e0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000019" can be put into a cast command `cast 4byte-decode 0x6352211e0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000019` and this reveals that the error was related to an ownerOf() method. So I was trying to treat this NFT as an ERC721 as opposed to ERC1155 (which has multiple owners), so that's why it was throwing an error.